# My app Stopped Working When I Added TextChangedListener

Tags: android, android-textwatcher

I'm trying a simple Android application which has a `EditText` field. 
The App worked just fine until I added a **TextChangedListener** to the `EditText`. The app keeps stopping, and when I remove the **Listener**, it just works like nothing happened.

Any ideas about this problem?

Comment: Post some relevant code.

Comment: This the code i used  'EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);

        et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                
            }
        });'

Comment: Post your stack Trace.

Comment: ` et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });`

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to post it properly !!

Answer (score 0):

Please check you EditText that you initialise properly then call TextChangedListener.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //Do what ever you want
            }
        });
```

Comment: i did the same, all inside **protected void onCreate** and the app keep stopping unless i remove the **listener** !!

Comment: you should initialise your edit text before calling addTextChangedListener

Comment: i initialized it but nothing changed !!

Comment: `@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
    et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
            });
        }`

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{Com.****.****.****/Com.****.****.****.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)' on a null object reference......Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)' on a null object reference

Comment: It didn't find any editText name et2 in your activity_main.xml layout. Please check your Edit text name in your layout file and initialise properly in your java file